# what does show.bs.select stands for?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

In bootstrap select what does this show, bs and select stands for? How can we change this accordingly ?

I have come across `show.bs.select, show.bs.dropdown, hidden.bs.select, hidden.bs.dropdown`.

What is this select and dropdown ?

Comment: is that helpful ??

Answer (score 0):

its seems like class selector , so `select and dropdown` is going to be class on select tag.

example

```
 $(".classA.classB").css("background-color", "yellow");

<p class="classB">Element with classB (won't match)</p>
<p class="classB classA">Element with classB and classA (match)</p>
```

will select second `p` element.

so it used for selecting element with multiple classes